# Suspend and power off are not reliable - Ubuntu 18.04.01 on Lenovo G70-80

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, acpi

I am experiencing problems with suspend and power-off after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS.

I have tried multiple fixes, including:

- Installing **pm-utils**
- Testing several kernels: **4.14.96, 4.17.19, 4.19.18, 4.20.5**
- Adding the parameters **acpi_osi=! "acpi_osi=Windows 2015"**  to the
  default linux command line in **/etc/default/grub**

In all cases, suspend and power off will work sporadically, but are not reliable.

I am hoping that someone with a Lenovo machine can advise me of a fix that has been proven reliable.

Details of my configuration are available:

- [inxi output](https://pastebin.com/j6BYc9aj)
- [/boot/grub/grub.cfg](https://pastebin.com/2Edhxn1t)

Thanks for your help.

JGB